# JS: How to reset index inside a for-loop so it loops again without lots of timeout errors?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm working on a custom JS thumbnail changer and it works. I want it to loop the thumbnails indefinitely. At the moment it just goes until `i==thumbs` and then stops. Here is the codesnipped:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= thumbs; i++) {
    timer[i] = setTimeout("Thumbchange('" + image_id + url + i + '.jpg' + "')", i * 100 * 10);
}
```

What I want is, if `i` reaches `thumbs` (the last thumbnail), reset `i` to 1 and play the `for` loop again. But I can't get it to work.

I tried lots of things including the following, but it crashes my browser because of timeouts: Can I somehow get around that timeout problem completely?

```
for (var i = 1; i <= thumbs; i++) {
    timer[i] = setTimeout("Thumbchange('" + image_id + url + i + '.jpg' + "')", i * 100 * 10);

    if (i == thumbs) {
        i = 1; 
        clearTimeout(timer[i]); 
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to do this for X number of times, or forever? ;)

Comment: `if (i==thumbs)` should do it, but ... this will result in an endless loop

Comment: `setTimeout("Thumbchange('...` please don't do that anymore

Comment: I modified the question to be more specific. Thank you all for your helpful suggestions.

Comment: @VitaliyPetrychuk how would you write that line to bypass the setTimeout problem?

Comment: @TinaMartinesz, like this: `setTimeout(function() { Thumbchange(image_id + url + i + '.jpg'); }, i * 100 * 10)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively use `setInterval` which will automatically loop forever or until you clear it.
Note that in `setInterval` and `setTimeout` you should use functions not evaluation strings.

```
var img = 0;

Thumbchange (image_id + url + img + '.jpg'); // Initialise img 0
window.setInterval (function () {  // Invoked once per interval
  if (++img == thumbs) // inc image and reset to 0 when it reaches thumbs
    img = 0;
  Thumbchange (image_id + url + img + '.jpg'); // do image change
}, 1000);  // 1 second per image
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (i<=thumbs) {

    // do stuff before i increments

    if(i===thumbs) {
       i = 0;
    } else {
       i++;
    }

    // do stuff after i was
    // incremented

}
```

But keep in mind that a loop written this way will run forever, thus having a *large* performance impact.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that `i` will never reach value of `>thumb` because this is the termination condition of your loop.

Your problem is at this condition:

```
if (i>thumbs)
```

Change it to:

```
if(i == thumbs)
```

Now your code should look like this:

```
for (var i=1; i<=thumbs; i++) {
    timer[i] = setTimeout("Thumbchange('" + image_id + url + i + '.jpg' + "')", i*100*10);
    if (i==thumbs) {
       i=1; 
       clearTimeout(timer[i]); 
       continue;
       }
  }
```

Comment: To prevent crashes because of timeouts, is there a way to modify the for-loop so it does not rely on `setTimeout`?

Answer (score 0):

Using a `setTimeout` in an endless loop is a bad practice, because you end up creating thousands of timeouts in a little time.
That's why your browsers crashes. In (let's say) 5 seconds you end up creating (let's say) 10000 timeouts, and the browser can't keep up with that, and thus crashes because you are consuming too much memory.

It would be better to create a new timeout after the last one was fired.

```
var i = 1;
var changeAfterTimeout = function () {
    i++;
    // check if we have finished the thumbnails. If so, start over
    if (i == thumbs) {
        i = 1;
    }
    Thumbchange(image_id + url + i + ".jpg");
    // call again after 5 seconds
    setTimeout(changeAfterTimeout, 5000);
}
changeAfterTimeout();
```

In this way, at any given time, we have **just one** timeout running.

Comment: Your answer gave me a lot of insight, thank you. Is there a way to not rely on specific timeouts (like 5 seconds) at all?

Comment: What do you mean? Are you talking about having to specify the 2nd parameter of `setTimeout`?